# apktool not working its showing andriodmanifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, apktool

```
Desktop$ apktool d -f mini.apk
 07:16:48 up 1 day, 11:43,  1 user,  load average: 0.53, 0.80, 1.09
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user     tty7     :0               Sat19   35:43m 32:05   1.42s /sbin/upstart -
I: Using Apktool 2.0.2-dirty on mini.apk
I: Loading resource table...
I: Decoding AndroidManifest.xml with resources...
I: Loading resource table from file: /home/user/apktool/framework/1.apk
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=versionCode, value=0x00000076
I: Loading resource table from file: /home/user/apktool/framework/1.apk
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=versionName, value=0x0000002a
I: Loading resource table from file: /home/user/apktool/framework/1.apk
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=versionCode, value=0x00000076
I: Loading resource table from file: /home/user/apktool/framework/1.apk
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=versionName, value=0x0000002a
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at brut.androlib.res.util.ExtMXSerializer.writeAttributeValue(ExtMXSerializer.java:38)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer.attribute(MXSerializer.java:696)
    at org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.XmlSerializerDelegate.attribute(XmlSerializerDelegate.java:106)
    at org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.writeStartTag(StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.java:267)
    at org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.event(StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.java:211)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.XmlPullStreamDecoder$1.event(XmlPullStreamDecoder.java:83)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.XmlPullStreamDecoder.decode(XmlPullStreamDecoder.java:141)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.XmlPullStreamDecoder.decodeManifest(XmlPullStreamDecoder.java:153)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ResFileDecoder.decodeManifest(ResFileDecoder.java:140)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.decodeManifestWithResources(AndrolibResources.java:199)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.decodeManifestWithResources(Androlib.java:140)
    at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:100)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:165)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:81)
```

After that it is not decoding..and showing only `Andriodmanifest.xml`

i am using java
 java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: did you find an anwer to your problem?

Comment: Nope left it as it is and moved forward

Comment: ahahahah time flys :) thanks for the update!